# How can I fix the error null error occurred while writing the flutter model?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class DiaryTagList {
  List<String> tagList;

  DiaryTagList({this.tagList});

  DiaryTagList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    tagList = json['tag_list']?.cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['tag_list'] = this.tagList;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I got an error like this,

```
The parameter 'tagList' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
```

How can I put a default value in ListtagList in flutter?

I'm a beginner, can you show me a simple example?

Comment: try `List<String>? tagList;`

Comment: Shouldn't be null, how can I get an empty [] array to be created if null?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At this line `tagList = json['tag_list']?.cast<String>();` you are saying that the `json` can result to a `null` value. However, your `tagList` is defined as `non-nullable`. You can make `tagList` `nullable` by adding `?` at declaration, `List<String>? tagList;`.

Comment: Shouldn't be null, how can I get an empty [] array to be created if null?

Comment: Try `tagList = json['tag_list']?.cast<String>() ?? [];` but `cast` may fail if the json is null, so you better go with `tagList = json['tag_list'] == null ? [] : json['tag_list']?.cast<String>();`